# Is there something similar to Android's dimens.xml in iOS?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I recently found out that I should be placing all my sizing/dimensions in `dimens.xml` for Android applications that I want to support multiple screen resolutions.

Is there something similar that I should do in iOS to support multiple screen resolutions? I code all my views in the back end (no storyboards) and when I want to position a view (padding, margins, etc.) I simply add hard-coded numbers to the `X` and `Y` properties of the view's `frame`. Same thing for `Width`, `Height`, `Font size`, etc. I imagine my iOS apps that I coded like this will look awkward on different screen resolutions like this?

By the way, I'm using Xamarin (Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS). But I would understand answers using native code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing like `dimens` in iOS.

I believe proper constraints with `AutoLayout` can work well on `padding`,`margins`,`Width`,`Height`,etc.

However, if you still want to find a way to achieve it , here is a temporary workaround.

#### Create a static Class named `Dimens`.

```
public static class Dimens
{
    public static int Height
    {
        get {
            string device = DeviceHardware.Model;

            if (device.Contains("iPhone4"))
            {
                return 10;
            }
            else if (device.Contains("iPhone5"))
            {
                return 15;
            }
            else if (device.Equals("iPhone 6") || device.Equals("iPhone 6S"))
            {
                return 20;
            }
            else if (device.Equals("iPhone 6 Plus") || device.Equals("iPhone 6S Plus"))
            {
                return 25;
            }
            //other device 

            return 0;
        }
    }      
}
```

#### Usage:

```
View.Height = Dimens.Height;
```

[Here](https://github.com/dannycabrera/Get-iOS-Model) is the plugin which can check your device type.

Comment: 1+  for nice as i thinking same.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an empty swift file, and use struct instead of dimens.xml for Android

```
struct Padding {
    static let left = 10
    static let right = 10
    static let top = 10
    static let bottom = 10
}
```

Comment: But then how which I choose which `struct` or swift file to use for the device that my app is running on?